# Difference between Ubuntu and Xubuntu when deploy to Server?

Tags: xubuntu

When deployed to a server (or via a VPS/cloud provider) what is the post install difference between Ubuntu and Xubuntu server (no X components, no WM)?

Thanks

Comment: Without X and WM I don't think there is any difference ? I don't think xubuntu provides `server` iso ? So, the answer would be None. http://askubuntu.com/questions/89951/kubuntu-v-s-xubuntu-v-s-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing an Ubuntu server it doesn't by default have any of Ubuntu/XUbuntu desktop components. so there is no difference as such. I would like you to provide more information on what exactly you are trying to do. It will make it easier for people here to provide their suggestions.